# Ionic 3 side menu title center

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have created ionic project from cli. Ionic version is 3. I am trying to make title image in center. Somebody please help me

```html
<ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color='primary'>
      <ion-title>
        <img src="assets/imgs/logo.png" width="128" />
      </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<!-- Disable swipe-to-go-back because it's poor UX to combine STGB with side menus -->
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use ionic CSS utilities to align center

```
<ion-title text-center>
    <img src="assets/imgs/logo.png" width="128" />
</ion-title>
```

Read More about css utilities

https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/

Answer (score 1):

When you want to center an element, add the `text-align: center` property to its parent element.

In your case, you need to change the code to:

```html
  <ion-title style="text-align: center">
    <img src="assets/imgs/logo.png" width="128" />
  </ion-title>
```